# When ceiling fan chain is pulled the rotation of the blades reverses. Fan will not stop while turned on

Tags: light-fixture, ceiling-fan

So I have a ceiling fan that when the switch is turned on the fan will not stop. When you pull the chain that should control the speed of the fan it simply reverses the rotation of the fan, all while stuck on high speed. So if I want to use the light on the ficture the fan is running full bore in one direction or another. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: What country is this in?  In the US, all the fans I've seen have a small switch to change direction, and the chain changes speed.  Perhaps someone custom wired this fan?  Or it's just a very odd control style.  How old is it, how old is the house?

Comment: Is this a new problem or have you just moved in and found this?

Comment: I'm located in the US. The fan is in an apartment I just moved into .The fan itself isn't old, I'd guess no more than 10 years old. The situation sucks because I cannot use the light without the fan running full force. Also the fan has no switch to make it change direction like every other fan I have ever seen. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Also the brand is Hampton Bay

Answer (score 3):

"Apartment" in the US means rental. Hate to say it, but *call the landlord*. DIY electrical in a rental is verboten in the US - any damage you might cause *will* be billed to you!

Basically, though, it sounds like someone wired the ceiling fan *and* the light to the switched hot instead of wiring the fan to an "always hot" and leaving control of the fan to the pull chain.

TBH, it sounds like someone, possibly a previous tenant, may have done their own wiring to have disabled the pull chain.

I'd get the landlord in ASAP so they know it's not you who did the work so they don't try blaming you. I'd also request that the landlord have his electrician give the rest of the place a once-over to ensure there isn't any other pirate electrical work the previous tenant did that you might get blamed for.

Comment: I understand all that in regards to liability issues with the landlord. I'm more interested in figuring out how the pull chain of the ceiling fan could only change the direction of the rotation of the blades and not the speed. Has anyone ever heard a problem like this?

Comment: Pirate wiring, @Aaron. I'm guessing the previous tenant wanted it working that way and rewired the internals of the fan to connect the reversing switch to the pull chain, and the switched hot to the fan as well as the lights. Even if you don't see a reversing switch on the outside, the wiring for it is likely still on the inside and just connected together, bypassing where the switch would go on a reversible one. This way, previous tenant got reverse.

Comment: TBH, I've never seen a fan _without_ a reversing switch. Maybe you just missed it? Maybe this one doesn't have one and that's just outside my realm of life experiences.

Comment: As far as I can tell there is no reverse switch. It's the craziest thing I've ever seen. If I could I would upload a video of it working

Comment: @Aaron if the previous tenant did pirate wiring to change the pull chain to reverse, you wouldn't see the reverse switch anymore because it has been modified.